# Can't call any method of authenticate webapi, even login or register

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have created web API with authentication, but when I try to register to it using console application I am getting following error:

> response = {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version:
>   1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?RDpcU1RFQ0hfUHJvamVjdFxQcm9qZWN0c1xMb3lhbHR5XFNhbnN1dGVjaC5MdHkuRGF0YS5XZWIuQXBpXGFwaVxBY2NvdW50XFJlZ2lzdGVy?=
>   Cache-Control: private Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 WWW-Authenticate:
>   Bearer, Negotiate, NTLM X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

How can I register to api using console client?

i can call register method from `postman` and get register to the application

here is the my console code to register

```
static async Task<string> PostRequest4(string token, string apiBaseUri, string requestPath, RegisterBindingModel t)
    {
        HttpClientHandler hndlr = new HttpClientHandler(); 
        hndlr.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //setup client
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:38811/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //make request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestPath, t);
            //make request

            Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ResponseMessage));
            ResponseMessage objResponse = (ResponseMessage)dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
            string res = "";
            if (objResponse == null)
            {
                res = "error occurred!";
            }
            else
            {
                if (objResponse.ErrorMessage != null)
                {
                    res = "error occurred!";
                }
                else if (objResponse.IsSuccess)
                {
                    res = "Item ID " + objResponse.ID.ToString() + " have been added Successfully!";
                }

            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

before pass if i add following line then i can successfully register to the application

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Here i got token by the following method using an existing user "user name and password"

```
private static async Task<string> GetAPIToken(string userName, string password, string apiBaseUri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //setup client
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //setup login data
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"), 
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName), 
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password), 
            });

            //send request
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(Token , formContent);
            //get access token from response body
            var responseJson = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
            return jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
        }
    }
```

i want to call register method without involving existing user(user name and password)

I will be very grateful if somebody can help me.
~Thanks~

Comment: Is your register method or it's controller is decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute? Try annotating with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on top of your `Register` action method.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have tried that. and also [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous] but still same,

Comment: Did you check on `[Authorize]` as well? I guess most likely problem is with Authorization only based on error message you posted. Also check how token validation happening in your application and if it is validating for `Register` method as well.

Comment: yeah i have tried [Authorize] as well. then it will return unauthorized error in postman also.i can call those method from postman without any token or credential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting anonymous authentication enable from project properties solved my problem.thank for